# Variable depth recursion in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, concurrency, recursion

So I'm doing a little experiment on exactly how far recursion can go in the Java language since I'm taking a class on concurrency and learning about Java's threading mechanisms. Right now I'm running a Intel i5 Quad-core with 2.8 GHz and 4GB of RAM. I'm running on Windows 7 with x64 and in Eclipse with the standard JRE? Not sure about that last part I just downloaded something from Sun's website.

Anyway,

```
public class StacksizeTest implements Runnable {

int depth = 0;

public void run()
{
    try
    {
        doOverflow();
    }
    catch (StackOverflowError e)
    {
        System.out.print("Overflow ocurred at depth " + depth + ".\n");
    }
}

void doOverflow()
{
    depth += 1;
    doOverflow();
}

public static void main(String argv[])
{
    Thread mt = new Thread(new StacksizeTest());
    mt.start();
    mt.run();
}   
}
```

I'm also running with the default call stack size, which im pretty sure is 512Mb according to the settings file.

So when I run the program and start a new thread I keep getting variable depths, as well as the print statement printing twice. The print statement makes sense I think because it should be running mt on a new thread. What I'm confused about is if I exclude .start() and just call .run() the "depth" is always the same (about 11,500 or so), but when I use .start() I'm getting variable depths. a couple have been 22789, 22330, and 22381. I'm having difficulty understanding why this is. Could someone possibly shed some light on this issue?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to `.start()` will start a new thread with `run()`, *then* you're calling `run()` again on the main thread. So you've got two stack depth threads running at the same time. Since you've also got a shared variable counting the depth that's not protected by a synchronized mutex, you've got a classic variable contention problem.

In order not to confuse the issue with variable contention, I would limit yourself to *one* running instance of the stack depth checker.

Comment: oh so you're saying that the depth variable is being called by both threads and it's a rough addition of both threads executing?

Comment: That's right. It's not a proper addition because you have thread contention: (thread 1) read depth, (thread 2) read depth, (1) add 1, (2) add 1, (1) store depth, (2) store depth. That bit of code would have intended to add two to `depth`, but the second "store depth" overwrote the effect of the first one and ended up only adding one.

Comment: Not exactly. There's no synchronization, so everything is possible. Each Thread may keep it's own version of depth in register, so you may end up with two independent variables. Or they may be "nice" and work on a common variable. One the the threads may run faster than the other. Basically, you end up with the completelly useless numbers, somewhere between N and 2*N, where N is the result obtained by using a single thread.

Comment: *(continued as I hit the comment length limit)* The compiler could also choose to do a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call optimization, so turning recursion into iteration, so there'd no more stack overflow (pun not intended). AFAIK, current JIT is not capable of this.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `start()` you're firing off the method asynchronously, so you're running it twice because `start()` eventually makes a call to `run()`, and in addition you're calling `run()` yourself, so you've got two threads incrementing your `depth` counter. Eliminate the `start()`, and you get your smaller count because you're only running a single thread.

EDIT: I just saw Greg's answer. I like his more.